# Why I can't do a build for Linux?

Tags: unity

I'm using Unity 5.3.x (free version) on a Windows machine. 
I would like to build my simple desktop game either for Windows and Linux, but Linux (and Mac) build is disabled.
Am i missing something ?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to install support for each platform you want to build for when you download the engine. Looks like this:

[image]

Make sure you click Linux Build Support. To fix your installation, you can re-run the download assistant for the version of Unity you have, and just select the build support ones and it will add them.